# How to create one gradient to more than one button, like Google plus discover buttons.

Tags: html, css

I have been working on a project that contains some button in the same way the Google plus buttons work, I want to style them in the same way, one gradient to all of them,

please help me.

Check the buttons. 
https://plus.google.com/discover/

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8MXJ.jpg

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried already.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how google do it, but I would use a fixed gradient background.

`background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);` add a standard gradient background to the buttons going from a red to yellow, you can use any colors you like.

`background-attachment: fixed;` fix the background in place so it's in the same place for all divs.

This will work for buttons that are all different lengths, but for the example I use a fixed length.

```css
.button {
  float: left;
  background: linear-gradient(-90deg, red, yellow);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="button"></div>
```

Comment: Google uses selectors for each button (`:nth-child(16n+1)`, `:nth-child(16n+2)`, etc.) with `background: linear-gradient(...)` on each set so that the gradient for one starts where the previous ended. I frankly like your solution much better.

Comment: Thanks,  That's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To reach this effect you have to use css gradients.
You do not have some code we could show you on so read more about here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Comment: I know that!!, I need one gradient to all the buttons.